# How to find a form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms on a page. How do I find a form by its name? I think in pure javascript it is something like document.forms['FormName'] .

I want to do a form.submit. But I want to be able to select a form by its name.

Comment: There could quite well be dozens of ways to do this. How about posting the code you want to actually use?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'find'. As a selector in jquery: $('#FormName') Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I just want to find a form by its id...thats all I want.

Comment: You asked `How do I find a form by its name?` but now you are telling something else, what do you exactly want ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the form you want:

```
$('form[name="foo"]')...
```

Comment: +1 - probably the cleanest way to do this, and attribute selectors are amazingly powerful.

Answer (score 15):

No jQuery required -- just use the built-in JavaScript `submit()` method:

```
document.forms['FormName'].submit();
```

Comment: +1 it doesn't get much simpler than this

Comment: This is not what the question was. The author has specifically stated they wanted to use jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Give your form an ID or class attribute.  In the case of an ID:

`$("#formName").function()`

Your HTML:

`<form id="formName">`

Where function is what you plan on doing...

Comment: The question is how to find the form by name not using id.

Comment: I think the OP is more confused than you may realize. "I just want to find a form by its id...thats all I want"